# Vertex-theme menu fonts are illegible?

Tags: xubuntu, themes, fonts

Not too sure why this happens but I used to have perfect white font over here in my old machine, with the exact same configuration in theme (vertex-dark) and ubuntu mono fonts. Even the theme configuration palette colour choices are the same. Where can I make this font white again?

[image]

I'm using Xubuntu 16.04.3

Comment: Use Window Manager settings to change the window border theme

Comment: Thanks a lot!! can you put this as an answer so that i can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to non-matching window manager theme because in XFCE, window manager theme doesn't change from appearence settings. Use Window Manager settings to change the window border theme from **Settings Manager**.